# How to print string War Games style one letter at time on same line in java

Tags: java, string, printing

using this code at the minute which I found on the net

```
 String welcome = "Would you like to play a game?";
 for (int i = 0; i < welcome.length(); i++) {
      System.out.println(welcome.charAt(i));

    }
```

Pretty basic stuff, but it prints out really quickly and line by line, how can i add a small pause, and print immediately after the previous character? So by the end it just says Would you like to play a game?

Im working in CMD, and Sublime text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use System.out.print instead of println. Use Thread.sleep to pause. Loop until the whole string is printed out.

```
String welcome = "Would you like to play a game?";
for (int i = 0; i < welcome.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(welcome.charAt(i));
    Thread.sleep(1000L); // in milliseconds
}
System.out.println(); // start a new line
```

Thread.sleep throws InterruptedException. If this code goes in your main method, the easiest way to handle it (assuming you have no interest in canceling the thread by interrupting it) is to add `throws InterruptedException` to the main method declaration (the exception will not get thrown, you're just keeping the compiler happy).

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply, that fixed the line per letter problem lol.
Ive never used the sleep thing, where in the loop would I sleep, I assume after the print. Will test! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`. To add a small delay the easiest thing is to use `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: Same as above, thanks for reply! that fixed the line per letter problem :-)
Ive never used the sleep thing, where in the loop would I sleep, I assume after the print. Will test! thanks

Comment: Exactly, after each print. And at the end (outside the loop) you can do a `System.out.println("");` or `System.out.print("\n");` to print the newline after all letters have been printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < welcome.length(); i++) {
      System.out.print(welcome.charAt(i));
      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
```